# Reconnect if internet lost

Tags: networking, network-manager

Is there any way to reconnect wired/wireless connection if some server (e.g. google) not responding? I have a rare issue connection getting lost randomly because of something (Other devices, connected to the same network, are fine, reconnect on my target machine is working too) and I need to make PC reconnect wired connection if something like ping throws errors. I cannot make it directly because I'm using this PC as remote ssh server so it must be available anytime to connect to it. May be there's something that already bundled with ubuntu distribution or simple sh script?

Comment: Years ago I had some network problems (a dying switch psu) so hacked a script to find it.  The script would ping devices; incremented $errors if no reply otherwise $errors=0;sleep 30. When ($errors>threshold) it would either `paplay` sound (on desktop), or ran another script that reset my network on my servers.  It didn't take long to hack together

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `bash` script to automatically reconnect my WiFi, see https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git - Watch for (WiFi) network going down, then do a user-specified thing to fix it.

It uses `ip monitor address`, and, when it sees `'^Deleted [[:digit:]]+: [[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]+inet[[:space:]].* scope global '` in the output, it executes "the next thing" from a user supplied list of commands. It then rotates the list, so next time it will try the 2nd, 3rd, ... eventually wrapping around to the 1st command on the list.